# Mongoose: How to find by 2 fields where one field exists in document and other in sub-documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below is my schema.

```
var prayerSchema = new Schema({
    totalSteps:{
      type: Number
    },
    name: String,
    steps: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Step'}]
});


var stepSchema = new Schema({
    stepNumber : {
       type: Number
    },
    _prayer : {
         type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Prayer', required: true
    } 
 });
```

Each prayer will have totalsteps, name and steps. 
Each steps will have stepNumber and prayerModel associated with it. 
Step document will look like this:

```
{
   "stepNumber":1,
   _prayer:[
       "name":"prayer1",
       "totalSteps":5,
       "steps":[]
    ] 
 },
 {
    "stepNumber":2,
    _prayer:[
        "name":"prayer2",
        "totalSteps":10,
        "steps":[]
     ]   
  }
```

I am trying to query by name exists in sub-document(_prayer) of stepSchema and stepNumber of stepSchema.

```
Step.find({_prayer :{ name: req.query.name} }, {stepNumber: 1});
Step.find({'_prayer.name' : req.query.name, stepNumber: 1});
```

Both these above codes didnot work.
One way I found is to query **Prayer**  document first by its name and get its _id and query again **Step** document by the found _id and stepNumber.

```
Prayer.findOne({name:"name"})
   .exec((err, prayers) => {

    Rakah.find({ _prayer: prayers._id, stepNumber: stepNumber })

    ....
});
```

But this approach will become difficult for nested documents.  
Are there any ways to query by one document only to get the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both filtering conditions should be included in one object of [find](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find) like this:

```
Step.find({'_prayer.name' : req.query.name, stepNumber: 1 })
```

Second parameter represents projection part so you were simply getting only `_id` and `stepNumber` (`1` means that field should be included in results)

Comment: Edited that line. But results are not coming.

Mongoose debug show like this;
Mongoose: rakahs.find({ '_prayer.name': 'Fajr', rakahNumber: 1 },

Comment: @Sulaiman there's no `rakahNumber` in your schema. Why are you trying to filter by such field ?

Comment: sorry that is stepNumber

Comment: @Sulaiman you can check it here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/LDVK6nESFXv

Comment: Working fine in mongo playground but not working in my code. thanks for your help. 
my mongoose version is 5.2.1